# 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host when running dockerd

Tags: kernel, docker

I'm trying to install Docker on Ubuntu 16.04.

When I run 'sudo dockerd' I get the following output:

```
INFO[2019-08-07T11:53:16.596291506+02:00] Starting up                                  
INFO[2019-08-07T11:53:16.607249544+02:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2019-08-07T11:53:16.607283194+02:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2019-08-07T11:53:16.607307827+02:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] }  module=grpc
INFO[2019-08-07T11:53:16.607321529+02:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2019-08-07T11:53:16.609233034+02:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000724420, CONNECTING  module=grpc
INFO[2019-08-07T11:53:16.610499127+02:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000724420, READY  module=grpc
INFO[2019-08-07T11:53:16.611838901+02:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2019-08-07T11:53:16.611855393+02:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2019-08-07T11:53:16.611870736+02:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] }  module=grpc
INFO[2019-08-07T11:53:16.611880821+02:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2019-08-07T11:53:16.611921584+02:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0006be600, CONNECTING  module=grpc
INFO[2019-08-07T11:53:16.612241184+02:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0006be600, READY  module=grpc
ERRO[2019-08-07T11:53:16.614741393+02:00] 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded.  storage-driver=overlay2
ERRO[2019-08-07T11:53:16.616112616+02:00] AUFS was not found in /proc/filesystems       storage-driver=aufs
ERRO[2019-08-07T11:53:16.617426685+02:00] 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded.  storage-driver=overlay
WARN[2019-08-07T11:53:16.649342023+02:00] Your kernel does not support oom control     
WARN[2019-08-07T11:53:16.649388044+02:00] Your kernel does not support memory swappiness 
WARN[2019-08-07T11:53:16.649403622+02:00] Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit 
WARN[2019-08-07T11:53:16.649415331+02:00] Your kernel does not support kernel memory TCP limit 
WARN[2019-08-07T11:53:16.649431429+02:00] Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts          
WARN[2019-08-07T11:53:16.649463707+02:00] Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts       
WARN[2019-08-07T11:53:16.649473137+02:00] mountpoint for pids not found                
failed to start daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted
```

It tells me 'overlay' was not found as a supported filesystem. However, overlay should be installed from kernel version 3.18

I'm using:

> 4.4.0-042stab139.1

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please check with this link 
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33689 
if you don't find it helpful then 
check with the fresh installation steps(please consider as it is written, you have to add docker repo not docker ubuntu16.04 repo , it had worked for me)

1. Add gpg key
2. Add docker repository to the APT sources
3. Update your system
4. `apt-cache policy docker-ce` //install docker repo
5. output of the above command will give you something like
   display of candidate key & version table
6. `sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce`
7. check docker status by `sudo systemctl status docker`

Comment: you can also check here https://askubuntu.com/questions/870889/cant-start-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-driver-not-supported-error